# Expand matrix based on first row value (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, matrix, rows

My input is the following:

```
X = [1 1; 1 2; 1 3; 1 4; 2 5; 1 6; 2 7; 1 8];

X =

 1     1
 1     2
 1     3
 1     4
 2     5
 1     6
 2     7
 1     8
```

I am looking to output a new matrix based on the value of the first column. If the value is equal to 1 -- the output will remain the same, when the value is equal to 2 then I would like to output two of the values contained in the second row. Like this:

```
 Y =

     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     5
     6
     7
     7
     8
```

Where 5 is output ***two times*** because the value in the first column is ***2*** and the same for 7

Comment: @Bitwise : Not very large, will be less than 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
% untested code:
Y = []; % would be better to pre-allocate 
for ii = 1:size(X,1)
   Y = [Y; X(ii,2)*ones(X(ii,1),1)];
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it is (vectorized):

```
C = cumsum(X(:,1))
A(C) = X(:,2)
D = hankel(A)
D(D==0) = inf
Y = min(D)
```

**Edit:**

Had a small bug, now it works.